# Subsetting data in Python seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

How can I use a subset of my age data within a boxplot? 
I only want to include rows with positive age values as you can see below:

```
import seaborn as sns
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1,figsize=(15, 8))
sns.boxplot(x='country_destination', y='age', data=train['age' > -1], palette="muted", ax =ax)
ax.set_ylim([10, 60])
```

The error message I get is:

> TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Comment: You are probably looking for something like ```train[train['age'] > -1]``` (but i didn't use much pandas recently). This has not much to do with seaborn and you really should grab some pandas basics! From a python-view: ```'age' > -1``` is evaluated before anything else happens; and a string does not compare to an int; therefore the error! The above, which maybe is valid, would grab the column and use it's values for comparison to -1, which might be ok, given the column type is a valid type.

Comment: Great thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pandas concern and not a seaborn issue.  You can do this with the appropriate use of `df.drop`.  This example shows how to achieve what you are after.  Just replace `data=train['age' >-1]` with the `df.drop(df[df.age<0].index` statement below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(14).reshape(-1, 2), columns=['country_destination', 'age'])
df.age = df.age - 4
print(df) 
print(df.drop(df[df.age < 0].index))
```

Comment: You’re welcome. Please accept the answer if you can.